# How to get the header URL of a Facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I'm developing a `Facebook` app and I need to get the URL of the page where the app is installed to set their share buttons and other params.

Thanks!

Comment: Not typing in all caps will help you find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the page id from the signed request (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) and then call `/PAGEID?fields=link` and pull out the link value.  This would be the url.